# Migrating an ASP.NET app to Java

Tags: java, asp.net, migration, web-frameworks

I'm trying to migrate a small ASP.NET MVC 2 app to Java on Tomcat 6.  I know the basics of JSPs and servlets.  I don't know any MVC Java web framework.  So I'm trying to determine how to proceed in a way that will keep the migration effort to a minimum.  I know I'll have to rewrite the app in Java but how do I map ASP.NET concepts to Java world?  What Java web framework should I choose given my lack of experience and my deadline of 4 weeks from now?  What's the most agile way to go about this?  Note that I can't use Grails or JRuby or anything like that.  This port must be done using standard Java web frameworks.  I also won't have admin access on the production Tomcat server that this will eventually deployed to.

Are there any migration guide that would be useful? Among other things, I need to understand how best to rewrite the security [current using ASP.NET profiles] and database access [currently using LINQ].

Answer (score 1):

Why "This port must be done using standard Java web frameworks"? Is it your boss' requirement?

If really so then it looks like you have not much choice. Strictly speaking a "standard" framework is the one supported by Oracle. Below is what I found on oracle site:  http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadp.html

It looks like currently only JSF is mentioned and thus recommended. I recall more technologies were recommended before?

- The Java EE 6 Tutorial Part II The
  Web Tier Part II

  - Chapter 3, Getting Started with Web Applications
  - Chapter 4, JavaServer Faces Technology
  - Chapter 5, Introduction to Facelets
  - Chapter 6, Expression Language
  - Chapter 7, Using JavaServer Faces Technology in Web Pages
  - Chapter 8, Using Converters, Listeners, and Validators
  - Chapter 9, Developing with JavaServer Faces Technology
  - Chapter 10, Java Servlet Technology

Comment: Yeah, JavaServer Faces (JSF) is the MVC to use with Java.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Scooter framework is a rapid web application development framework which just requires developers to know basic JSP/Servlet and MVC concepts. Since your deadline is only 4 weeks away, you can try it. It comes with many examples. See the Hello World example and [Blog](http://scooterframework.com/docs/blog.html) example. The downside is it may not support LINQ. It does support Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL.